# 'NoneType' object is not callable error when trying to pull a number off webpage

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, nonetype

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'https://app.wonderland.money/#/dashboard'
response = requests.get(url, timeout=5)
content = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")

backing = content.findALL(attr={"class":"card-value"}).text
print(backing)
```

im trying to pull a specific number off a website, but I keep getting a 'TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable' error. Im not sure how to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

#### What happens?

Take a look in your `soup` there is no such `class` or element your looking for, cause content is provided dynamically and `requests` do not work the same way a browser does - It will not interpret `javascript` and render the website.

#### Possible solution

Try to use [selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/getting-started.html) instead to grab the page source.